# is image-map (with <area> tag) still the way to do it?

Tags: html, image, imagemap

I have a diagram, which I got from a psd file.

I need to have a few elements in that diagram clickable.
Basically it's a circle,the center and four areas in the cardinal
directions (N,S,E,W) need to be clickable.

Is an image-map with `<area>` tag still the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. [Image maps are still very much allowed to be used with HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#image-maps) and if they solve what you are trying to do, you can use them as much as you want. However, an alternative to image-map is to use [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html) which gives you many more options both in terms of animations and effects, but also some new event triggers (onmouseover e.t.c).